# Is this method of opening an endpoint secure? (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm thinking through how to open an endpoint to my customer so he/she can trigger changes in their model from an external website (aka an API i think?)

I plan on creating an action in my controller where I skip authentication and authenticity token check. I would create a long random string to give to my customer so when they submit a POST request, they would include the random string in the params to confirm identity.

Is this a secure way of doing what I'm trying to do? Is there another/better way of doing this?

I just want my customer to be able to pass me values and my app take actions based on these values.

Answer (score 1):

what you are talking about is usually called client token authentication.

i use it for my app as well: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/blob/master/app/controllers/api_controller.rb#L23-L29

my implementation uses a header-field to exchange the token.

if you want to have a more sophisticated variant you should look at oauth.

in terms of security, you might take additional measures by whitelisting ip ranges etc.

of course, use SSL connections only!